# Python Traceback Error When Reading Json File

Tags: python, json, data-analysis, tweets

I just extracted my all my tweeter history in a json file. so I want to do some data analysis on the tweets with python. I open the terminal and and entered the following commands to dump json from from python.

```
>>> import json
>>> with open('tweet.js') as json_file:
...     data = json.load(json_file)
...     print(data)
```

and got this "traceback" error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\George\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 4771: character maps to <undefined>
```

the json file is name tweet.js and it follows this form

```
{
  "retweeted" : false,
  "source" : "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>",
  "entities" : {
    "hashtags" : [ ],
    "symbols" : [ ],
    "user_mentions" : [ {
      "name" : "Florin Pop \uD83D\uDC68\uD83C\uDFFB‍\uD83D\uDCBB",
      "screen_name" : "florinpop1705",
      "indices" : [ "0", "14" ],
      "id_str" : "861320851",
      "id" : "861320851"
    } ],
    "urls" : [ ]
  },
  "display_text_range" : [ "0", "155" ],
  "favorite_count" : "0",
  "in_reply_to_status_id_str" : "1194246195243302913",
  "id_str" : "1200417547524493312",
  "in_reply_to_user_id" : "861320851",
  "truncated" : false,
  "retweet_count" : "0",
  "id" : "1200417547524493312",
  "in_reply_to_status_id" : "1194246195243302913",
  "created_at" : "Fri Nov 29 14:13:40 +0000 2019",
  "favorited" : false,
  "full_text" : "@florinpop1705 I've heard good things about it, but never tried it.... Using kdenlive is simple yet some things are difficult to implement like text effect",
  "lang" : "en",
  "in_reply_to_screen_name" : "florinpop1705",
  "in_reply_to_user_id_str" : "861320851"
}
```

Comment: The snippet you've given is valid JSON. What you _haven't_ given is the actual full traceback with the error so we can see what it complains about

Comment: Just to clarify: There is no "traceback error", there is an "error traceback" the trace through the stack from the entry point of your application to the place where the error happened.

Comment: @miatech The error you are facing is : "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 276: character maps to <undefined>" Please update the full traceback error. Check out the solution mentioned.

Comment: @roganjosh  I just updated the error output... check it out. I included encoding but that didn't fix it

Comment: @Vaibhav Jadhav just updated error output

Comment: @miatech. Yes i know you are facing this error. I have updated the solution. Please check it.

Comment: @miatech Did you checked the solution?

Comment: yes, I can open other json files but not that one, I think it might be the formatting or something. the file has the js extension but when I open it gives me errors...

Comment: @Vaibhav Jadhav is it possible that special characters in the file could be causing errors?

Comment: @miatech I don't think so it will give an error. Because i have used your json file to check the output and it works as per my solution.

Comment: You can check by keeping .json as extension with new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will give you output,encoding="utf8" must be added.You specify the encoding when you open the file:

```
import json
with open("tweet.json", encoding="utf8") as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
print(data)
```

Comment: still got the error... I think is the json file it's got the extension js and I think is the formatting or something, because I can open other json files no problem

Comment: @miatech I have used your json file to check the output and it works as per the solution.

Answer (score 0):

actually, it is a trouble with formatting, i copied your .json into the online pretty print and it make it look normally

also, just to alert, do not forget about additional tabs or enters, they can provide such mistake